# Почему не фильтруется список при нажатии на кнопку?

Tags: angular4, фильтрация

Привет сообщество.
 Начал изучать Angular 4 по книге Адама Фримена "Pro Angular" (только делать начал на Angular 5).
 Согласно книге создается магазин товаров с различными категориями. Дошел до места где создается фильтрация по категориям общего списка товаров. Код и разметку копировал из книги (поэтому свою разметку не стал выкладывать), но в этом месте мой результат не совпадает с учебником, а именно список не фильтруется. Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему с фильтрацией списка. 
Вот мой ts-код:

```
    import {Component, ViewEncapsulation} from "@angular/core";
    import {Product} from "../model/product.model";
    import {ProductRepository} from "../model/product.repository";

    @Component({
      selector: "store",
      templateUrl: "./store.component.html",
      moduleId: module.id,
      styleUrls: ["./store.component.css"],
      encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
    })
    export class StoreComponent {
      public selectedCategory = null;

      constructor(private repository: ProductRepository) {
      }

      getProducts(): Product[] {
        return this.repository.getProducts(this.selectedCategory);
      }

      getCategories(): string[] {
        return this.repository.getCategories();
      }

      changeCategory(newCategory?: string) {
        this.selectedCategory = newCategory;
      }
    }
```

Скриншоты кода и разметки из книги:

[image: код из книги]
[image: html-разметка из книги]

Comment: думаю ошибка в шаблоне. Отправьте и шаблон. Шаблон это .html

Comment: @qwerty я уже разобрался. В версиях Angular новее, чем 4.0.0 (используется в книге), код из книги уже не работает. Пробовал на 4.6.1 и 5.0 версиях